# A non-HTTP 200 response was received (400) for URL https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/xxx

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Has someone run into this problem in Xcode?

I was trying to run a sample iOS project on real device with personal team. with automatically manage signing on. But Xcode show the error:

> Communication with Apple failed
>   A non-HTTP 200 response was received (400) for URL https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/ios/submitDevelopmentCSR.action?clientId=xxxxxxxx

[image]

At first I thought this is a problem with apple's server. But 4 days later I still have this problem in my Xcode.

There are similar topics on apple developer forum but with no replies

here is the request failed detail

> 2018-11-29 02:00:01 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: 2018-11-29
>   02:00:01 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: Sending request
>   7D28B80A-3C7B-4535-A776-92FB191DF18B to
>   https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/ios/submitDevelopmentCSR.action?clientId=xxxxxxxx
>   for account weizhou.xxx@xxx.com. Payload: {
>       Accept = "text/x-xml-plist";
>       "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate";
>       "Content-Length" = 1516;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/x-xml-plist";
>       DSESSIONID = 177fh3khme0oc4ih6aqiqjrplffc4ntjniqpiifj9hlfll77puo6;
>       "User-Agent" = Xcode;
>       "X-Apple-App-Info" = "com.apple.gs.xcode.auth";
>       "X-Apple-GS-Token" = "AAAABLwIAAAAAFv9R0QRDWdzLnhjb2RlLmF1dGi9ALpO7vMavQV+BpusdOu2LPR9H0ZfEWnrOA/LVa6umyhuVLw0Qlp+S+0pECPe3Ag/87je9/r1yX0kaiU3aZXBfC7lLzrO1Uyqw6RBXzUKAE3RylC/yyR6amg6M0xFcHTQ2NUNGBST6UB6E7ABqQF970AuMVFE";
>       "X-Apple-I-Client-Time" = "2018-11-29T02:00:01Z";
>       "X-Apple-I-Identity-Id" = "001813-08-84bec2e6-c49c-468f-b046-5c73b7098776";
>       "X-Apple-I-Locale" = "en_CN";
>       "X-Apple-I-MD" = "AAAABQAAABDtg6G3vHzGPwm3p4Xf/gxUAAAAAQ==";
>       "X-Apple-I-MD-LU" = 5E67C8EC865A7D1B5D2D9DF4C4E0B94DAE6CC38031E39D6E0BD85C20A6262282;
>       "X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "zYf50UanS29ND7NL21VIyva+k49SRqLRI7kOAY76AfIvGfPBYDhsA1iUY+xRXGuotqtrKz1Kmm4RreIZ";
>       "X-Apple-I-MD-RINFO" = 17106176;
>       "X-Apple-I-TimeZone" = "GMT+8";
>       "X-MMe-Client-Info" = "  ";
>       "X-Mme-Device-Id" = "C30C07C8-C8CA-5F2E-9DC8-70AC10B934F6";
>       "X-Xcode-Version" = "10.1 (10B61)"; } {
>       "DTDK_Platform" = ios;
>       clientId = xxxxxxxx;
>       csrContent = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\nXRem8vVxrBnt\n-----END
>   CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n";
>       machineId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
>       machineName = "weizhou.xxxx\U7684iMac";
>       protocolVersion = QH65B2;
>       requestId = "7D28B80A-3C7B-4535-A776-92FB191DF18B";
>       teamId = xxxxxxxxx; }
>
> 2018-11-29 02:00:02 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: 2018-11-29
>   02:00:02 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: Received response for
>   7D28B80A-3C7B-4535-A776-92FB191DF18B @
>   https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/ios/submitDevelopmentCSR.action?clientId=XABBG36SBA.
>   Error = Error Domain=DVTPortalResponseErrorDomain Code=0
>   "Communication with Apple failed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=A non-HTTP 200 response was received
>   (400) for URL
>   https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/ios/submitDevelopmentCSR.action?clientId=XABBG36SBA}
>
> 2018-11-29 02:00:02 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: 2018-11-29
>   02:00:02 +0000 IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: Response payload: HTTP 400
>   Bad Request

Answer (score 2):

A week ago I started to run into the same problem. I tried the following:

- I logged into the Xcode bot user on the bot machine and opened Keychain Access. It showed several expired Xcode bot certificates. I deleted them and tried again. No success.
- I deleted and recreated the whole Xcode bot user. No success. Keychain Access now showed that the "Xcode Server Builder" certificate was invalid (not expired).
- I manually trusted the "Xcode Server Builder" certificate in Keychain Access WITH SUCCESS! Now the bots were building again.

This said, I do not know what the root of the problem is. At least this is a way to work around the problem.

Comment: how did you do this: manually trusted the "Xcode Server Builder"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and there were 3 simultaneous problems.

Our Apple Developer Agreement had expired. When logged into developer.apple.com/account there was a large banner saying our Account Holder had to accept new terms and condtions. I also could not access certificates or profiles until that was done.

Also one of my signing certificates had expired.

Xcode server was using an alternate certificate from the expired one. That has a missing private key. So I had to export the private key from KeychainAccess on my computer and install it on the bot server.

Then I archived my project and exported it manually on the bot server Xcode, so Xcode would download or update any other certificates and profiles it used. After that, I was able to do a remote bot build on the project.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue, some countries are boycott, I'm from Iran and I used VPN.
My problem with VPN was fixed